# Tagetes flower in Ukraine

Tags: culture, ukraine, history

I just returned from my first trip to Ukraine. Since I'm loving the [Tagetes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagetes) flower I was wondering why it is omnipresent in Ukraines streets and flowerpots. My first assumption was that it is related to the [Orange Revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange_Revolution) because of it's colour. But researching the internet asking some natives (mostly young people) did not result in an satisfying answer.

Why do Ukranians love this flower? Is there a historical, cultural or any other background for this?

[image]

Comment: Wikipedia article you reference says: "In Ukraine, chornobryvtsi (T. erecta, T. patula, and the signet marigold, T. tenuifolia) are regarded as one of the national symbols, and are often mentioned in songs, poems, and tales.". If you want songs named after this flower name, then [here you go](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%D0%A7%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%86%D1%96).

Comment: A [quick read](http://pti.kiev.ua/statti/776-zvdki-v-ukrayin-chornobrivc.html) told me that back in times it was used as diaphoretic specifically and also in general cooking. I suppose this is the source of the popularity.

Comment: Thank you for the links. I read the german wiki article where this is not mentioned and linked the english article here. Thats why I haven't seen this myself. Shame on me :)

Comment: Just in case you did not see the Ukrainian name for the flower yet, here it goes: Чорнобривці

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lol) 
The Tagetes from old times is considered one of symbols of Ukraine, a house and mother. There are even songs in that sung that when see this flower - remember a native house and mother. Why exactly this flower became a symbol it unknown. But it as tradition and he grows almost near every house in large and little cities)

Comment: What exactly do you mean with native house and mother? Can you provide a link or the title of a traditional tagetes song please?

Comment: There is a song, but she on Ukrainian . not sure that you will understand words) I found some articles, maybe from them you will understand https://www.facebook.com/AccommodationInKiev/posts/797476790314120 and http://botanic-life.com/en/pages/369148

Answer (score -1):

In fact, they are easy to take care of that's why they are everywhere. You throw a handful of seeds and they grow, or you buy seedings, plant them and they grow. You forget to water them for several days, or weeks, and they still grow even during hot summer in Southern Ukraine.

Comment: It's good to know that they're easy to care for but being a national symbol trumps that by a long way. For example, bald eagles aren't particularly easy to "care for" (i.e., maintain natural environment for) but the US put significant effort into increasing their numbers when the population fell to a few hundred breeding pairs in the 1950s.